# How to increase limit of graph in LINQPad?

Tags: linqpad

Results shown in LINQPad are limited. If objects are deep nested, a red line is shown.
I would like to increase a limit, so I can see more nested objects.

Do you know how to do it? (I have not find that in options.)

> **Background not in the original question:** LINQPad will display of
>   "limit of graph" error message if the total output exceeds a certain
>   threshold (total page size).
>   The suggested answers are addressing how to limit the depth of the individually dumped object 
>   graphs, which may help avoiding hitting the total size limit. It does not, however, increase the "limit of graph", which is what OP is asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try another overload of Dump() method.

Answer (score 7):

To flesh out @lioil's answer:

`Dump`'s overloads include:

```
T Dump<T>(this T o); //Dump the object and return it (for fluency)
T Dump<T>(this T o, string description); //Dump with label
T Dump<T>(this T o, int maximumDepth); //Dump with given maximum depth
T Dump<T>(this T o, string description, int maximumDepth); //Combine the above
```

You're looking for the third or fourth option.

Comment: But what is maximumDepth and how do I know what number to put there?

Comment: It's the answer to this question...the depth of the graph being shown on screen.

Comment: OP is asking how to increase the "limit of graph" (LINQPad shows an error saying "Limit of graph" when the output reaches a certain size. Limiting the depth of the object graph may help you in avoiding hitting the output limit, but it does not increase it.